# How to add a static bottom view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to add a static`UIView` in the bottom of my `UIViewController`. This is a story board app written in swift. in my `viewDidLoad()` I did something like this.

```
self.vWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
let mainBound = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-135, self.view.frame.size.width, 135)//CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 135.0)
self.vwVideo = UIView.init(frame: mainBound)
self.vwVideo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.vWindow.addSubview(self.vwVideo)
```

But this adds nothing to my `viewController`. Why is that? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: you can add it like : self.view.addSubView(self.vwVideo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
let vWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
let mainBound = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-135, self.view.frame.size.width, 135)//CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 135.0)
self.vwVideo = UIView.init(frame: mainBound)
self.vwVideo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
vWindow!.addSubview(self.vwVideo)
```

- Use this code it will add your view in window at the bottom side.

Comment: What is difference from user's question?

Comment: he takes the window object globle and I just make it local and you can test this code if you want.

Comment: Right @AshishKakkad i'm agreed with you.

Comment: @Jecky It makes no difference global is also working fine brother.

Comment: Yeah you right I am not saying that you are wrong. but with this 5 line of code I just added in my project and View is there. Then what's the wrong in it bro. Can you Justify ?

Comment: :( same result. why is that

Comment: @Jecky User's code is working as it is. in view controller.

Comment: did you put it in viewdidload()? Im loading many views after viewdidload()

Comment: @AshishKakkad I think you wanna say that user has posted a wrong question. :P

Comment: ohh its working when I put it in viewDidLayoutinSubview() :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be attaching views directly to the window, add it to the ViewController.

try something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        // without autolayout

        let header = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, view.bounds.size.width, 50))
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(header)

        // with auto layout
        let footer = UIView()
        footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        footer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(footer)


        NSLayoutConstraint(item: footer, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: footer, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: footer, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: footer, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true


    }
```

Here you have two ways of attaching the view, One with autolayout and one with a fixed size and position.

If you want to add complex views, you may be better creating a nib.. .a view in storyboard which you can load when required.

If you need this view to appear in many places you could look at instead attaching it to a parent view, maybe something like a navigation controller or paging view controller, but you would need to manage when it should and shouldn't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding your created view to `window` i think. You need to that view to your current content view something like,

```
 self.view.addSubView(self.vwVideo)
```

And you not need to take window and bounds of it, you can simply achieve it something like,

```
 let bottomView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 135, self.view.frame.size.width, 135))
 self.view!.addSubview(bottomView)
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to do it using AutoLayout.
Add your view to superview

`view.addSubview(footerView)`

then disable auto conversion of masks to constraints using

`footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

then add the constraint using following lines of code

`view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view":footerView]))`

`view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view(135)]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view":footerView]))`